# How do I set a maximum value in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I made an application in Tkinter and I want the user to be able to change the canvas size. When I click the button on the root it should open up a dialog that changes the size of the canvas. I also want to add a maximum value, so the user cant pick a width of more than 1300 and a height of 660.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("10000x10000")

canvas = Canvas().pack()

button = Button(root, text="Change Canvas Size").pack()

def changeCanvasSize():
    root2 = Toplevel(root)
    root2.title("Change the canvas Size")
    
    widthText = Label(root2, text="Canvas Width").pack()
    changeCanvasWidth = Entry(root2).pack()
    changeCanvasWidth.insert(0, "1100")

    heightText = Label(root2, text="Change Canvas Height").pack()
    changeCanvasHeight = Entry(root2).pack()
    changeCanvasHeight.insert(0, "566")

    applySizes = Button(root2, text="Apply", command = lambda: canvas.configure(width=changeCanvasWidth.get(), height=changeCanvasHeight.get()))


root.mainloop()
```

So how would I set a maximum value, width should be 1300 or less and height should be 600 or less. How would I do that?

Comment: `Entry` widgets support validation, so you could enforce limits that way. See [Adding validation to an `Entry` widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524022302id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) for more information.

Comment: Why use the dialog instead of letting them simply resize the window in the normal manner?

Comment: not the window...I am resizing the canvas.

Comment: The entry widget supports validation. It should be possible to prevent numbers greater than a certain value.

Comment: ok, do u have sample code.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use a if statement? and create a pop-up error message `

```
if changeWidth.get() > 1300:
   newLabel = tk.Label(text="Enter Number Less 1300")
```